# Dynamic Queries with Spring Data, JPA and Streams

Tags: spring, spring-data

We are using SpringData and JPA in our project. Large data sets are to be retrived from the database. Is there any way we can 'Stream' the results from database. I could find solutions where stream is possible with Spring Data but we have to use '@Query' or 'Named Queries'. As per our requirement we have to create query predicates (where clause) dynamically. With '@Query' and 'NamedQueries', its not possible to create dynamic queries. Please share if you have any solution.(we require Streams + dynamic queries)

Comment: you can use query parameters dynamically with @Query..what exactly mean dynamic queries?

Comment: It would appear this is not currently supported out of the box: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/issues/260

Comment: Maybe JOOQ? https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.9/manual/sql-execution/fetching/lazy-fetching-with-streams/